# Room does not update all queries properly with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have 120 records in a table and I want to update all records one by one. Somehow room can not update the whole records. out of 87 records can not be updated although I see log output. (I check the table by exporting to db browser for sqlite as well as getting data through code)

PreferencesActivity

```
private fun updateSample()  {
  for (x in 1..114) {
    preferencesViewModel.updateRecords(x)
  }
}
```

viewmodel

```
fun updateRecords(x: Int) = runBlocking {
  launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    database.surahDataDao().update(x, x, x)
    Log.e("AAAA", "database.preferencesDataDao().update($x, $x, $x)")
  }
}
```

dao

```
@Query("Update Preferences Set start = :start, end = :end WHERE Id = :number")
fun update(start: Int, end: Int, number: Int)
```

some log output from logger

runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] -> update(6236, 6231, 114)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main] -> update(6230, 6226, 113)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main] -> update(6225, 6222, 112)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main] -> update(6221, 6217, 111)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-6,5,main] -> update(6216, 6214, 110)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main] -> update(6213, 6208, 109)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-6,5,main] -> update(6207, 6205, 108)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-4,5,main] -> update(6204, 6198, 107)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] -> update(6197, 6194, 106)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] -> update(6193, 6189, 105)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-6,5,main] -> update(6188, 6180, 104)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-5,5,main] -> update(6179, 6177, 103)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-5,5,main] -> update(6176, 6169, 102)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main] -> update(6168, 6158, 101)
runs on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main] -> update(6157, 6147, 100)

.
.
.

Comment: With `runBlocking()`, I would expect an ANR. Assuming that `updateSample()` is called on the main application thread, your 114-call loop is going to tie up the main application thread for 114 individual database transactions. That has a decent chance of going past the ANR boundary, particularly on slower devices. Beyond that, I strongly recommend that you do all of this in a single `@Transaction`, rather than 114 individual transactions.

Comment: nope. I use launch(Dispatchers.IO) which makes the execution run on another thread. Otherwise how I'm supposed to update the other 87 records?

Comment: "I use launch(Dispatchers.IO) which makes the execution run on another thread" -- and the `runBlocking()` then blocks the current thread, waiting for the launched coroutine to complete.

Comment: Are you printing the log from you `updateRecords` function? The log seems to be a little suspicious. Where is that log output you are printing coming from?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari yes it is. I've just changed the log output text

Comment: @CommonsWare so? How do I use coroutines then? By the way, I also tried async await and ExecutorService. The result was the same.

Comment: "How do I use coroutines then?" -- I would first focus on the `@Transaction`, as that is significantly more important. If `@Transaction` supports `suspend`, then in my `ViewModel` I would use `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {}` and call my `suspend` function in there. If `@Transaction` does not support `suspend`, then in my ViewModel` I would use `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { } }` and call the non-`suspend` function within the `withContext()` lambda.

Comment: But still there is one thing that I can't understand, why more than half of items can be updated if it is a blocking thread issue?

Comment: Actually there are still other threads which are waiting for to be executed however the program thinks everything is done before threads that are waiting get executed I guess?